# MySQL: Order by not in the correct order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get this query to order from the highest qtyOrdered to the lowest though when I run it, it does the opposite. The result is the qtyOrdered running from the lowest to highest. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my SQL:

```
select Product.productId, Product.prodName, OrderedProduct.qtyOrdered, CustOrder.orderDate
from Product
join OrderedProduct
on Product.productId=OrderedProduct.productId
join CustOrder
on CustOrder.orderId=OrderedProduct.orderId
where qtyOrdered >= '50'
and orderDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'
order by qtyOrdered;
```

Comment: you need to add DESC ,order by desc for descending, ASC for ascending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `DESC`, which means "descending" (highest to lowest), after `qtyOrdered`. The default is `ASC`, for "ascending", which is lowest to highest.